# (Fake proof) Bounded linear operators $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ between separable Banach spaces $X$, $Y$ is itself a separable Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, fake-proofs

**Fake proof:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be separable Banach spaces. We know that the space $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ of bounded operators $X \to Y$ endowed with the operator norm is itself a Banach space. (Cf. [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023681/is-y-is-a-banach-space-if-bx-y-is-a-banach-space)[[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946247/collection-of-all-bounded-linear-operators-from-x-into-y-is-a-normed-linear)[[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602041/if-space-of-bounded-operators-lv-w-is-banach-v-nonzero-then-w-is-banach-not).) So we need to show that $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is separable.

It is known (cf. p.14 of Alexander S. Kechris, *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*) that the closed unit ball of $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ with the subspace topology inherited from the strong operator topology of $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is separable. (Cf. [[4]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293531/homeomorphic-closed-copy-of-the-unit-ball-of-the-space-of-bounded-linear-operato)[[5]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125903/separability-of-unit-ball-in-strong-operator-topology).)

However, if the unit ball of a normed vector space is separable, then the entire vector space must be separable. (Cf. [[6]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498281/unit-ball-in-a-separable-banach-space)[[7]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295842/unit-ball-separable-longrightarrow-space-separable).) Therefore $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is separable (in the strong operator topology), so "$\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is a separable Banach space".

> **Why proof is fake (?):** The main issue is that the operator norm topology on $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is being conflated with the strong operator topology on $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. Is that correct?
>
> The strong operator topology on $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is separable but need not be (complete) metrizable. In contrast, the operator norm topology on $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is (complete) metrizable but need not be separable. (Cf. [[8]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495231/separability-of-bounded-operators-on-normed-spaces)[[9]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3334640/separability-of-banach-space).) Is that correct?

E.g. in general the strong operator topology on $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ [is generated by semi-norms [10]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/269974/606791) in some sense related to the operator norm, but [in general is not even metrizable [11]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298775/is-the-strong-operator-topology-metrizable) and thus clearly not induced by the operator norm and not a Banach space. Cf. also this question [[12]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711541/completeness-and-separability-of-bx-bounded-linear-operators-on-x).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Separability for different topologies bears no relation.

You can see this clearly when $X=Y=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. You can embed $A=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ into $L(X)$ as multiplication operators. That is $$M_xy=(x_ny_n).$$ This embedding is isometric when you consider the operator norm. As $A$ is not separable, neither is $L(X)$. On the other hand, $L(X)$ is separable in the strong/weak operator topology since $X$ is separable and the finite-rank operators are dense in $L(X)$ in the weak/strong operator topology.

Comment: To clarify, what is the relationship between compactness and separability of the unit ball being used here? Or is it just that the proof that (unit ball separable) $\implies$ (whole space is separable) requires the assumption that the unit ball is compact? Is this referring to a special case of Banach-Alaoglu? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Sequential_Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem Sorry, my functional analysis is really rusty and was never very good to begin with, that's why I was confused about this at first before realizing the argument is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, is it just that compactness is a sufficient condition for separability in this case? (Because closed unit ball is closed subspace of complete metric space induced by the norm, so a complete metric space) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974233/prove-if-x-is-a-compact-metric-space-then-x-is-separable

Comment: My bad. I have no idea why I talked about compactness. Answer edited.

Comment: No worries, the given example is still really clear/good/helpful/etc.